# php update data from multiple checkboxes

Tags: php, checkbox, editing

i have a table called horse, i would like to create a form to edit the horse_name and horse_height, but the data cannot be updated, it turns out there is a problem with the update query, when i print the query to show the values, the horse_name value is equal to horse_height

```
<body bgcolor="#009933">
<?php
     include("connection.php"); 
     $conn = oci_connect($UName,$PWord,$DB);
     if(empty($_POST["check"]))
     {
    $query="SELECT * FROM horse ORDER BY horse_name";
    $stmt = oci_parse($conn, $query);
    oci_execute($stmt);


   ?>
<center> <font face="Arial" size="3"><b>Horse Details</b></font>
</center>

<form method="post" action="multiplehorsemodify.php">  
<table border="1" align="center">
  <tr>
  <th>Horse ID</th>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Height</th>
  <th>Edit?</th>

  </tr>


  <?php 
        while($row = oci_fetch_array ($stmt))
        {
  ?>
         <tr>
         <td><?php echo $row["HORSE_ID"]; ?></td>
         <td align="center">
         <input type="text" size="24" 
            name="<?php echo $row["HORSE_ID"]; ?>" 
            value="<?php echo $row["HORSE_NAME"]; ?>"></td>

         <td align="center">
         <input type="text" size="5" 
            name="<?php echo $row["HORSE_ID"]; ?>" 
            value="<?php echo $row["HORSE_HEIGHT"]; ?>"></td>
         <td align="center">

<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="<?php echo $row["HORSE_ID"]; ?>">

      </td>

         </tr>
  <?php 
        }
  ?>
  </table>
<center>
    <input type="submit" 
      value="Update Selected Titles" />
  </center>
</form>
<?php
    oci_free_statement($stmt);
     }
     else
     {
         foreach($_POST["check"] as $horse_id)  
         {
             echo $horse_id;
             $query = "UPDATE horse set horse_name = ".$_POST[$horse_id]."horse_height = ".$_POST[$horse_id]." WHERE horse_id = '".$horse_id."'";
             echo $query;
            $stmt = oci_parse($conn,$query);
            oci_execute($stmt);
            header("location: multiplehorsemodify.php");
         }
     }
     oci_close($conn);
?>

</body>
```

Comment: im sorry, how can i copy html code here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you set `name` and `height` both to `$_POST[$horse_id]` in your query:

```
$query = "UPDATE horse set horse_name = ".$_POST[$horse_id]."horse_height = ".$_POST[$horse_id]." WHERE horse_id = '".$horse_id."'";
```

And you even give the input elements the same name:

```
name="<?php echo $row["HORSE_ID"]; ?>"
```

The name of an input element becomes the key of the `$_POST` array on the PHP side. So give the input fields the right names, e.g.:

```
 <input type="text" size="24" 
        name="horse_name[<?php echo $row["HORSE_ID"]; ?>]" 
        value="<?php echo $row["HORSE_NAME"]; ?>">

 <input type="text" size="5" 
        name="horse_height[<?php echo $row["HORSE_ID"]; ?>]" 
        value="<?php echo $row["HORSE_HEIGHT"]; ?>">
```

and change your query to

```
"UPDATE horse set horse_name = ".mysql_real_escape($_POST['horse_name'][$horse_id])
."horse_height = ".mysql_real_escape($_POST['horse_name'][$horse_id])
." WHERE horse_id = '".$horse_id."'"
```

Comment: this way, the value of horse_name and horse_height point to the last horse in the list

Comment: @chandra wib: Have you really tested with the last version? Basically you have to create an array for the names, like you did for `check[]`. Sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 1):

Both of your form fields have the same name ($row["HORSE_ID"]) which will cause problems!

Answer (score 1):

```
 <input type="text" size="24" 
                name="HorseName"
id="name-<?=row["HORSE_ID"] ?>" 
                value="<?php echo $row["HORSE_NAME"]; ?>"></td>

             <td align="center">
             <input type="text" size="5" 
                name="HorseHeight" 
id="height-<?=row["HORSE_ID"] ?>"
                value="<?php echo $row["HORSE_HEIGHT"]; ?>"></td>
             <td align="center">
```

This way, you can still use the id to make the checkboxes for the particular horse unique

UPDATE:

Go ahead and do it like this for each horse:

```
<input type="text" size="24" name="HorseName"  value="<?= $row["HORSE_NAME"] ?>" />
<input type="text" size="5" name="HorseHeight"value="<?= $row["HORSE_HEIGHT"]; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="HORSE_ID" value="<?= $row["HORSE_ID"] ?>" />
```

Then your php and query can look like this:

```
$HORSE_NAME = $_POST['HORSE_NAME'];
$HORSE_HEIGHT = $_POST['HORSE_HEIGHT'];
$HORSE_ID = $_POST['HORSE_ID'];

"UPDATE table_name SET HORSE_NAME = $HORSE_NAME, HORSE_HEIGHT=$HORSE_HEIGHT WHERE HORSE_ID = $HORSE_ID"
```

Comment: what should i do with the query?

Comment: There you go Chandra, does that help?